# Como acessar um virtualhost local de outro dispositivo?

Tags: redes, dns, ip, apache

Eu estou precisando testar uma aplicação local que roda no Apache2 no meu celular e em outros dispositivos aqui.

Eu costumo configurar meu Apache2 no Linux da seguinte forma:

No `/etc/hosts`, coloco o domínio desejado:

```
  127.0.0.1 dev.local
```

E no VirtualHost, configuro o mesmo:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName dev.local
     DocumentRoot  /var/www/dev.local/public
</VirtualHost>
```

São essas as configurações que uso, mas eu queria saber se teria alguma forma de expôr esse VirtualHost `dev.local` para outras máquinas poderem acessar o mesmo.

Eu até tenho uma solução que consegui, que é dar um bind em `0.0.0.0` com uma porta e usar meu ip local para acessar via dispositivo, mas ela demora demais pra carregar a página.

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Em casa eu tenho um mikrokit e basicamente tenho o mesmo ambiente que você, eu adicionei um DNS estático, que direciona para o ip do meu servidor apache. seu gate e um linux ou um mikrotik ? ou um roteador mais parrudo ?

Comment: @Bulfaitelo tô usando um wi-fi? Teria como fazer via wi-fi?

Comment: No meu caso qualquer forma eu consigo acessar o servidor. sim por wifi, mas pra isso eu preciso entender seu ambiente,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu conheço e testei a ferramenta [ngrok](https://ngrok.com). Com ela você expõe sua porta para acesso num endereço na internet. Nunca usei profissionalmente, apenas para testes em casa mesmo, mas acredito que dê para você testar o seu servidor de desenvolvimento.
Ele disponibiliza dois endereços um em http e outro em https.

### Edit

Achei essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108483/access-localhost-from-the-internet) no SO em inglês que indica mais dois serviços que fazem o mesmo:

http://localtunnel.me/

http://localhost.run/

Comment: Interresante, vou dar uma olhada.

Answer (score -2):

Sei que já fazem quase 3 anos, mas gostaria de compartilhar a solução que encontrei, afim de que outras pessoas que encontraram essa question possam tentar também.

O que fiz foi configurar diferentes portas para acessar diferentes vhosts através de outros dispositivos na mesma rede. Bem como se você acessar o ip da interface de rede cabeada (ex.: 192.168.0.2) pelo celular, irá carregar por padrão a porta 80, que equivale ao seu localhost da máquina principal, abrindo a página padrão configurada do apache.

Dito isso, você pode alterar a porta utilizada pelo vhost de 80 para 81, por exemplo. Assim:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
     ServerName dev.local
     DocumentRoot  /var/www/dev.local/public
</VirtualHost>
```

E configurar o arquivo `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` para escutar a porta 81 além da 80. Bastando inserir `Listen 81` abaixo de `Listen 80`.

Ficando da segunte forma:

```
...    
Listen 80
Listen 81

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
...
```

Em seguida é só reiniciar o apache. (no linux com: `sudo service apache2 restart`).

E acessar `<ip>:81` (ex.: `192.168.0.2:81`).

---

Observações extras:

- o endereço de acesso na máquina dev deverá ter :81 no final. (ex.: `dev.local:81`)
- A linha `Include ports.conf` deve estar descomentada no arquivo `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.
- se precisar descobrir o ip para acessar pelo dispositivo secundário, digite `ifconfig` no terminal linux da máquina dev (ubuntu ou derivados no meu caso). Geralmente a segunda linha do retorno no terminal irá lhe indicar o ip.